# Which of the following graphs represent functions whose derivatives have a maximum in the interval $(0, 1)$?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Which of the following graphs represent functions whose derivatives have a maximum in the interval $(0, 1)$ ?

[image]

My reasoning goes like this:

> From the graph sketches, we can readily conclude, that all of the $4$ graphs are continuous in the interval $(0,1).$ Now, we use the following theorem on continuity:
>
> - The function $f(x)$ continuous on the the interval $[a,b]$, possesses the following properties:
>
> $(1)$ $f(x)$ is bounded on $[a,b]$
>
> $(2)$ $f(x)$ has the minimum and maximum values on $[a,b]$
>
> $(3)$ If $m=\text{min}_{a\leq x\leq b} f(x)$ and $M=\text{max}_{a\leq x\leq b} f(x),$ then for any $A$ satisfying the inequalities $m\leq A\leq M,$ $\exists$ a point $x_0\in [a,b]$ for which $f(x_0)=A$
>
> - In particular , *if a function is defined and continuous in some interval, and if this interval is not a closed one, then it can neither have the greatest nor the least value.*
>
> In all these graphs, it is seen that, in the interval $(0,1)$ all the 4 functions sketched, are continuous. Since, $(0,1)$ is an open interval and from the above theorem, neither of the functions do not have the greatest nor the least value in this interval.
>
> In option $A$ we see, that $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing, and hence, $f'(x)<0,$ and since $f$ has no maxima and minima in the open interval, $f'(x)$ is always, negative and itself a decreasing function. So, $f'(x)$ never attains a maximum value, since there is no greatest value of $f(x)$ nor any least value of $f(x)$.
>
> In option $B,$ it's a monotonically increasing function, and $f'(x)>0$. But by analogous reasoning as above there is no, maximum value of $f'(x)$.
>
> In case, of the last two options, by similar reasoning, $f'(x)$ has no maximum value.

However, I feel that something is wrong with my solution. I don't know what it is. Is the above solution correct? (As neither of the options seems correct, according to my solution ) If not, where is it going wrong? I am not quite getting it.

A thing to add: Is there a general way of solving these sort of problems. I am anticipating, a preferable way, of solving these sort of problems, in an mcq(Multiple Choice Question) exam, where one has a time constraint.

*I know, that some users don't advocate the use of pictures, but the graphs are part of this problem and so, I attached them, as seen in the beginning of this post.*

Comment: Theorems are off topic here. You are just asked to interpret the graphs. E.g. in A, $f$ is decreasing but $f'$ is not. The slope stays $<0$ but first increases and then decreases.

Comment: Are you looking at the slopes of tangent lines?

Comment: Let us delete those comments above which have become useless, and try a more direct approach. Look again at A and imagine you can measure the slopes of the tangent lines, from left to right. They will be sth like $-4,-2,-1,-2,-4$ and the maximal slope (the maximal value of $f'$) will be $-1.$ (I chose these precise numbers at random, it is just to indicate how the slope evolves.)

Comment: @AnneBauval Now, that you mention, yes, I found graph A to be a lot similar to $-x^3$ and the maximum value of the derivative of $-x^3$ is attained at $0$. But then, here it says, that the maximum derivative at $(0,1)$ which excludes $0$. So, that appears as a point of concern. I concentrate on the second approach you demonstrate: you mention that   the numbers are chosen  randomly. I understand the value of the slope repeats *intuitively*. But I dont get, how we conclude, that  there's a maxima in the slopes of the tangent...

Comment: The graph of $-x^3$ for $x\in(-1/2,1/2)$ has roughly the same shape as A (I prefer $-x^3-x$ so that the maximum of $g'$ (at $x=0$) is $<0$ like in A instead of $=0$). The graph of $-(t-1/2)^3$ for $t\in(0,1)$ is the same, translated horizontally so that the maximum of the derivative is at $t=1/2.$

Comment: In my last approach of A, the (negative) slope increases continuously from (something like) $-4$ at $x=0$ to $-1$ at $x=1/2$ and then decreases continuously until $-4$ at $x=1.$ So, its maximum value is attained at $x=1/2.$

Comment: @AnneBauval What I am doing is: I am drawing some tangents at every point in graph $A$ and am checking those (imaginary) drawn tangent lines are subtending an acute or an obtuse angle with positive direction of $x$ axis, then I find, that as we move done the curve in $A$ the angles of tangent lines with $x$ axis becomes larger and larger i.e obtuse and reach when the angle has a value of nearly 180 degrees , at which the slope is maximum and then the value of slopes starts repeating. : Is this what you mean ? Correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: Yes, that is it ([my slopes are the $\tan$ of your angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope#Algebra_and_geometry)).

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok, that makes it clearer really! Also, in my opinion it is really an efficient process in an mcq test to get the answer intuitively. But this is a question where more than one option can be correct. How do we proceed to eliminate the rest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145077/discussion-between-anne-bauval-and-franklin).

Answer (score 0):

Does it have a maximum value or maximum absolute value?  If it's maximum value it's the steepest uphill slope (since the steeper the slope, the larger the value of the derivative), if it's maximum absolute value it's the steepest slope which can be either uphill or downhill.  It's either B or D since A and C have functions that get steeper outside of that interval.

Comment: This answer is not completely clear and anyway wrong: 1) absolute values are off topic. 2) in A for example, the derivative does have a maximum inside the open interval and in D it does not.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw it said $a$ maximum rather than $the$ maximum, so you're right.

Comment: That is not the problem. Your main misunderstanding, I think, is to consider absolute values. E.g. $f'$ can have a *negative maximum*.

Comment: Okay, go ahead and post a better answer then.